# Recovering Source Code from Unfinished App on Android Phone

Tags: java, android, eclipse, intellij-idea

For the past month and a half I have been working on a project, an app for Android.  Today my computer crashed.  Apparently the backup didn't backup the source files for any of my projects though; it only backed up the drawable folders for some reason?

Anyway, I was wondering if there was a way to recover the source code from the app on the phone somehow.  I never fully finished the app and created an .apk or anything, but I ran it on my phone several times for debugging purposes, so it is on my phone in a fairly recent state.  Is there a way to somehow recover the source code for this?  I would hate to have to redo anything, but it seems like I'm probably going to have to end up doing that.

I began the project in Eclipse Indigo but later switched IDEs to IntelliJ IDEA.  The files I currently have on my computer are:

- An EML file for the project.  It appears to be blank.
- The drawable folders

And that's it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried [AndroChef](http://www.neshkov.com/ac_decompiler.html), which is based off of Fernflower, a decompiler which is by a user here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dex2Jar to get a jar and then use JD-GUI to examine the code. Since it is decompiling it will not be exact, but close.

dex2jar: http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/

JD-GUI: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/

Comment: YES!  I figured it out; it works!  It's a bit different but I think I can figure out how to fix it.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could look into this as an option:

> It is a tool for reverse engineering 3rd party, closed, binary Android
>   apps. It can decode resources to nearly original form and rebuild them
>   after making some modifications; it makes possible to debug smali code
>   step by step. Also it makes working with app easier because of
>   project-like files structure and automation of some repetitive tasks
>   like building apk, etc.

http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/

Answer (score 0):

You can try file recovery softwares to get back your deleted files from your hard disk(if it is working).
These softwares worked for me in recovering pictures from a formatted SDCARD. So you can give it a try.

Comment: I managed to recover some of the files for the project.  However, open attempting to open them, they're just a bunch of gibberish and essentially useless in their current state.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use IntelliJ IDEA's "local history" feature. IntelliJ keeps track of all your edits in `.IntelliJIdea10` folder in the use home. If that folder has not been damaged in the crash you should be able to recover all your codes.

Just right click on the module directory in the **Project** tab and select **Local History** > **Show History**. Wait for the list of history items to load, it may take a couple of seconds.  Right click on an item in the left panel and select **Revert**.